# AngularJS typeahead add custom sort by function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to build a typeahead which should get a specified number of results and sort them by startswith.

This means if I do have the values: Alabama, Missouri, Maryland, Massachusetts, etc. and type in the input field "m" or "M" the order should be Maryland, Missouri, Massachusetts, Alabama.

Therefore my code looks like this:

```
<input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="selected" 
  typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
```

I tried by adding a custom filter function:

```
<input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="selected" 
  typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | orderBy:orderByStartsWith()| limitTo:8">
```

with the function:

```
$scope.orderByStartsWith = function() {
    return function(element){
        return element.toLowerCase().startsWith($scope.selected.toLowerCase()) ? 0 : 1;         
    }
};
```

This isn't working, because the scope value `selected` is not updating as shown in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7LA4/24/)

Is there any solution to get the desired order?

Comment: can you put a more complete example ? The fiddle shows what you expected when you type "Ma"

Comment: Thank you didn't saw this. I changed the question. If you only type "m" or "M" you should see what the problem is, because when I tried it Alabama is always at second position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the *$viewValue* to your order by function and use it to sort the results.

```
<input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | orderBy:orderByStartsWith($viewValue) | limitTo:8">

 $scope.orderByStartsWith = function(viewValue) {
      return function(element){
        return element.toLowerCase().startsWith(viewValue.toLowerCase()) ? 0 : 1;           
      }
    };
```

check the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2umL5yqL/1/

Comment: Solved it. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand `orderBy`, but how do you compare _two_ elements like in the standard JS `sort(function(a,b){...})` method?